# Peeves’ or Peeves’s?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

Why would Filch from Harry Potter 2 say: “… go now, I have to write up **Peeves’** report … go …”

Would saying **Peeves’s** have been a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether to *write* (or *enunciate*, in speech) that second (possessive) ***s*** after a subject noun that already ends with ***s*** is a stylistic choice. But the orthography should always reflect *how you **would** pronounce it* (if you had to actually read out your text, say).

It's the same with, say, ***Charles's wife, Jesus' life***. But note that to some extent writers/speakers may make different choices depending on exactly how easy they find it to articulate the repeated consonant with the *specific* noun (i.e. - any given person might not make *consistent* choices).

But I venture to suggest that if we postulate a context where there are already many instances of the potentially troublesome sibilant phoneme, such as a man with two "high maintenance" mistresses...

> *My **mistresses's** dresses are costing me a fortune!*

...no-one would actually write (or attempt to articulate) the final Saxon Genitive ***s*** unless they were being deliberately facetious.

Answer (score 1):

The possessive form of a singular nouns ending with the letter s can be either:

> The noun with a following apostrophe: Peeves' report.
>
> The noun followed by an apostrophe and another letter s: Peeves's
>   report.

Either is correct and the choice is a matter of style.

[Apostrophes with words ending in s](https://data.grammarbook.com/blog/apostrophes/apostrophes-with-words-ending-in-s/)